# I am getting this error django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-model-field

I am getting this error django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'icontains' for ForeignKey or join on the field not permitted

Below is **models.py**:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name
    
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    rating = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1), MaxValueValidator(5)])
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    is_bestselling = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="",null=False,blank=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("model_detail", args=[self.slug])    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Below is **admin.py**:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'rating', 'author','is_bestselling',)
    list_display_links = ('title', 'rating',)
    search_fields = ('title', 'rating','author',)
    list_filter = ('rating', 'is_bestselling',)
    prepopulated_fields = {
        'slug': ('title',)
    }

class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    list_display_links = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
    search_fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)
```

I was trying to search Author in my Books Model.

Comment: You should post the answer in the answer section (below) not include it in the question.

Comment: Ohk Sure @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 3):

The error you are encountering can be attributed to the utilization of the default search option in Django within your `admin.py` file.

Django's search option is designed to exclusively search for a field in the database, based on the column name rather than a table or row name.

To rectify this error, you have two potential solutions:

1. Conduct a search within one or two columns of the User model:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from . import models

@admin.register(models.Post)
class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    search_fields = ('title', 'body', 'author__username')
    ...
```

2. Alternatively, eliminate the author search functionality.